# Div disappearing during CSS animation

Tags: html, css

I made a simple animation (3 all together) but the second time it plays the `div` just outright disappears and then comes back after a few seconds.

My code:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  animation-duration: 10s, 5s, 7s;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse, alternate, alternate;
  animation-delay: 3s, 0s, 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 7, 6, 6 ;
  animation-name: move-away, color-change, big-to-small;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

@keyframes move-away {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

@keyframes color-change {
  from {
    background-color: #DCAB6B;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #7d4f50;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #8f250c;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #583101;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
}

@keyframes big-to-small {
  from {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  50% {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  to {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Animation</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspected the thing and it's just that the `<div>` has transparent background. This happened because the `color-change` animation has ended much sooner than the other ones and the `<div>` itself has no background color.

Increase one from following values make the `<div>` stay colored longer:

- `animation-duration`
- `animation-delay`
- `animation-iteration-count`

As bonus, you can set the `animation-iteration-count` of that animation to `Infinite` to make it loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your animations to run indefinately, consider using `animation-iteration-count` with the keyword `infinite` as the value. you can view the docs for it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Note you can also give multiple values if you want each animation to iterate a different number of times.